# GIF images in background image property need to stop animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image, animated-gif

On certain scenario I need to stop the gif image used in **background-image** property without using **src** attribute.  Kindly help to find the solution either in javascript or jquery. Thank you.

**Eg:**

```
background-image: url('http://www.webdeveloper.com/imagesvr_ce/webdeveloper/animation/bnifiles//knight.gif');}
```

Comment: Replace it with a static image.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without using the **src** attribute. JavaScript has no way of controlling the current frame of an Animated GIF. However, there is a plugin that could do the work for you. It's called [FreezeFrame Plugin](http://functionn.blogspot.hr/2012/11/freezeframejs-jquery-plugin-to.html#.V7xU2qLGvE8)

It uses canvas tag to create a still image from the first frame of the gif.

Changing the src attribute with static image would save you plenty of time.